# Condensate vs superfluid fraction in $\rm{}^4He$

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, bose-einstein-condensate, superfluidity

In the superfluid state of $\rm{}^4He$, it is known from neutron scattering measurements and Monte Carlo simulations that about 10% of the $\rm{}^4He$ atoms condense into the lowest energy state. Said another way, the largest eigenvalue of the diagonalized one-particle density matrix is about 10%. However, at low temperatures, the superfluid density approaches 100%. What constrains the whole liquid to exhibit superfluid properties despite only 10% of the atoms being condensed in the lowest energy state?

Comment: Is this much different from how not all electrons in a superconductor condense at zero temperature due to energetic considerations and you still have supercurrents? In the same way, He atoms have a repulsive hardcore interaction that ultimately prevents complete collapse of the momentum distribution.

Comment: This isn't much different than the case of superconductors. However, even in superconductors, there exists a difference there between the condensate density and the superfluid density. In a superconductor, as long as the superfluid density is non-zero, one will measure zero resistance in an electric transport experiment because the non-superfluid electrons will, in some sense, be short-circuited by those that do form the superfluid. But the question I am asking is: Why are the 4He atoms that do not condense into the lowest energy state (~90% of particles) still possess superfluid properties?

Comment: I don't know what you mean about the "90% still possessing superfluid properties", it's not like you can remove the condensed fraction and expect the fluid to still be a superfluid. It is a property of the whole system. Maybe you can be more concrete about what you mean by that.The same "short circuiting" happens in a superfluid as the superconductor. The non-condensed fraction at zero temperature doesn't live with speeds above the critical velocity where they can scatter and dissipate without a gap.

Comment: What I mean, for instance, is that at low temperatures, much below the superfluid transition temperature, if you rotate a cylindrical bucket of 4He, none of it rotates with the container (assuming the container is rotating slowly enough). This indicates that the superfluid fraction is essentially 1. However, as I mentioned in the question, it is known from QMC calculations and neutron scattering measurements (which are consistent with one another) that the condensate fraction is around 0.1 (i.e. there is a clear experimental difference between the superfluid and condensate fraction).

Comment: I think you are mixing up the normal state fraction, where you have occupation above the gap due to thermal effects, and He states which are below the gap but have k states different from the condensed fraction (which is still the case at zero temperature). Is your question how that can be?

Comment: No, I am not making that mistake. My question is correctly posed as stated in the question. There is a difference between the fraction of particles in the single-particle ground state and the fraction of particles that exhibit persistent currents or non-classical rotational inertia, as described in the rotating bucket experiment.

Comment: I did not suggest there isn't a difference between the superfluid fraction and condensed fraction. The point I am making is that there isn't a contradiction there unless you don't distinguish between different types of non-condensed states above and below the "gap". You may want to read this reference, which I can summarize as an answer if that is indeed addressing your confusion: https://arxiv.org/pdf/0804.3086.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the reference, it was helpful in clarifying what you meant. Unfortunately, I do not think many parts of the text are correct. Superfluidity is not just a property of the excited states. In the non-classical rotational inertia experiment I referred to, the property is of the ground state. This effect is analogous to the Meissner effect in superconductors, which is also a ground state property.